# Service Fabric - Local Cluster On VM Not Accessible Outside Network

Tags: networking, azure-devops, azure-service-fabric

I have a Virtual Box VM hosted on my desktop, using bridged mode.
On that VM I have installed a one node Service Fabric cluster (secured with a self-signed x509 cert).
I have setup my router to send ports 19000-19100 to that guest machine IP Address.
I am on AT&T Fiber so I am forwarding those ports to a router and then the router forwards them on to the guest OS at a specific IP address.

From my host machine I am able to get to the service fabric explorer and I can deploy services to it from visual studio.

I am not able to deploy to it from azure devops. My friend is not able to see the explorer either.

In DevOps I have configured a service connection, put the certificate in it, etc. In my pipeline I am writing to the hosts file (my public IP and the host name I need sit.mysite.com as an example). One thing to note is that I was previously able to deploy to SF when I had the cluster running on my main machine (as opposed to in a VM as it currently is)

A friend (living in another state) is not able to view my service fabric explorer. I provided the cert to him, he's imported it. He has an entry in his hosts file also. When he goes to https://sit.mysite.com:19080 (the SF explorer address), he gets a 403, not authorized. But it is correctly picking up the cert. He can also ping my IP address so we have connectivity.

Whatever is stopping him from hitting my SF is likely what is preventing me from the ability to deploy from azure devops, but I have no idea what it would be...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. Turns out my cluster config file was referencing localhost for the node as opposed to the IP (or a dns name) and that made the fabric not respond to requests from outside.

```
"nodes": [
        {
            "nodeName": "vm0",
            "iPAddress": "IP_ADDRESS_HERE",
            "nodeTypeRef": "NodeType0",
            "faultDomain": "fd:/dc1/r0",
            "upgradeDomain": "UD0"
        }
    ],
```